# The method 'get' was called on null when using stream builder. What is wrong in the code?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, stream-builder

I am building a mobile application using mvp in flutter. The problem i am facing is that the code i used to make the product screen and order screen is same, using **stream builder**. But in case of Product screen the code is working perfectly fine showing circular Progress indicator but when i navigate to order screen it first show me an error on order screen instead of circular progress indicator and after some milli seconds when it get the response it shows the result. I also attached the video here for better understanding. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4QX1-sKS9k

The init state method and build method of stateful widget are also same but i am not getting the problem where i am doing wrong in the code. The code of build state of order screen is below which is causing problem.

**Build method of order:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text(
        'Orders',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
    body: widget.myList.isNotEmpty //TODO update it remove the parameters
      ? orderListView(widget.myList)
      : StreamBuilder(
        stream: orderPresenter.getOrders,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<OrdersList> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return orderListView(
              snapshot.data.orders //TODO update it remove the parameters
            ); 
          } else if (snapshot.data.orders.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('Your orders are empty'),);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }

          return Center(
            child: Container(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
  );
}
```

**In Order Presenter we have**

```
final _ordersFetcher = PublishSubject<OrdersList>();

@override
Observable<OrdersList> get getOrders => _ordersFetcher.stream;
```

**Solution that worked for me:**

```
 if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );

                }else 
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                  orderListView(snapshot.data
                      .orders);
                }
```

Comment: You aren't checking for the case in which `snapshot.data.orders` could be null. That's what the error in your video is showing. Check for null and show the `CircularProgressIndicator()` while it is null.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your kind response i updated my post  with the solution that worked for me. Your answer show me the way how to correct it

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking for a case in which `snapshot.data.orders` could be `null`. That's what the error in your video is showing. Check for null and show the `CircularProgressIndicator()` while it is null. You can add it to your first if and it is `null` it will default to your already present `CircularProgressIndicator()` at the end of the `StreamBilder`:

```
if (snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.orders != null) {
  return orderListView(
    snapshot.data.orders //TODO update it remove the parameters
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your kind response i updated my post  with the solution that worked for me. Your answer show me the way how to correct it